# Is it possible to detect if the current while loop iteration is the last in perl?

Tags: perl, loops, while-loop

I never thought this was possible, but read some conflicting comments and thought I would ask the experts.

If I am progressing through a while loop that is reading a file line by line, is there a way to execute some code if the current iteration will be the final iteration in the loop? I understand that I could simply place this code immediately after the while loop, so that the code would execute after the last line, but I was just wondering if the iteration has any way of detecting it's position.

Thanks!

Comment: See Perl's [eof](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/eof.html).

Comment: Also note the distinction between `eof` and `eof()` - In a `while(<>)` loop, the shorter one may be true multiple times @ARGV has multiple files, and the longer one returns true only once.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the special case where you are reading from a file, yes.

```
while(<>) {
    if(eof) {
        print "The last line of the file!\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: @HunterMcMillen, in the general case, how would the loop know that the condition will be false the next time it's evaluated?

Comment: @jake9115: All it really does is move the `print "The last line of the file!\n"` inside the `while` loop, which some would say is a distraction.

Answer (score 4):

While there may be certain special cases in which is it possible to determine that the current iteration is the last, it is not possible in the general case.  A trivial example:

```
while (rand() < 0.99) {
  print "Hasn't ended yet\n";
}
```

Since it is not possible to predict what the next random number will be, it is clearly not possible to know whether any given iteration will be the final iteration.