# How to prematurely detect whether it's the last iteration during a while loop in Perl

Tags: perl

Similar question(does not solve my question): [Is it possible to detect if the current while loop iteration is the last in perl?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19390020/is-it-possible-to-detect-if-the-current-while-loop-iteration-is-the-last-in-perl)

Post above has an answer which solves the issue of detecting whether it's the last iteration solely when reading from a file.

In a while loop, is it possible to detect if the current iteration is the last one from a mysql query?

```
while( my($id, $name, $email) = $sth->fetchrow_array() ) 
{
       if(this_is_last_iteration)
       {
            print "last iteration";
       }
}
```

Comment: Why do you need to do this? That might help with getting a decent answer?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
my $next_row = $sth->fetch();
while (my $row = $next_row) {
    my ($id, $name, $email) = @$row;

    $next_row = $sth->fetch();
    if (!$next_row) {
        print "last iteration";
    }

    ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to verify this compiles, but a rough outline is:

```
my($rows) = $sth->rows;
my($i) = 0;
while( my($id, $name, $email) = $sth->fetchrow_array() ) 
{
    $i++;
    if ($i == $rows)
    {
        print "last iteration";
    }
}
```

If you give us some more context, there may be other options. For example, your `print` statement is the last thing in the `while` loop. If that matches reality, you could simply move this after the loop and do away with the counter.

A couple of commentators have correctly noted that the `rows` command will not always have the correct value for a SELECT command (eg. see [here](http://search.cpan.org/~timb/DBI-1.634/DBI.pm#rows)). If you're using `SELECT` (which seems likely from your code) then this could be an issue. You could perform a `COUNT` before the `SELECT` to get the number of rows *provided the data set does not change between the `COUNT` and the `SELECT`.*

Comment: Works! Thanks! & needed the print statement within the while loop

Comment: `rows` can't be used that way. The value it returns won't always be right

Comment: Agree with @ikegami. Better to do a `SELECT COUNT(*) ...` to get the number of rows ahead of time.

Answer (score 1):

Although you can count rows to tell when you are on the last result from an SQL query, **no, in the general case it is not possible to know in advance whether you're on the last iteration of a while loop.**

Consider the following example:

```
while (rand() > 0.05) {
  say "Is this the last iteration?";
}
```

There is no way to predict in advance what `rand()` will return, thus the code within the loop has no way of knowing whether it will iterate again until the next iteration starts.

Comment: Right, but there is a general solution. Applied to your example: `my $next = rand() > 0.05; while ($next) { $next = rand() > 0.05; ... if (!$next) { ... } ... }`

Answer (score -3):

You can keep a counter and compare it to the array length. I'm not familiar with Perl, but that's how I would do it in any other language.

Comment: There's no array here. Like in other languages, `while` loops repeat until a boolean expression returns false.

Comment: @ikegami Yes, there is an array. If you look at the accepted answer, he does exactly what I was proposing to do.

Comment: Re "Yes, there is an array", Wow, playing dumb, eh? Fine, let me translate: The items over which the loop iterates are not in an array. There is no length to be gotten.

Comment: Re "If you look at the accepted answer, he does exactly what I was proposing to do." The answer that doesn't work does exactly what you proposed? Not a ringing endorsement of your proposal.

Comment: @shieldgenerator7 - While the `fetchrow_array` method _does_ return an array, the array's contents are a single row returned from the query. There is no array containing all of the returned rows. `fetchrow_array` functions as an iterator, returning one row at a time until it runs out of rows. Depending on how a given database driver implements it behind the scenes and the total number of rows returned, it may or may not have an internal array containing all of the returned rows, but it generally won't, because it needs to be capable of handling result sets larger than available memory.

Comment: @DaveSherohman Thanks for the info! That clears up the confusion I had about it. But even though you don't have an actual array, is there a way to get the number of rows that will be returned?

Comment: DBI offers the `rows` method, which is used in the accepted answer, but its accuracy is dependent on the actual database in use - some will return the actual total number of rows, some will return the number of rows read _so far_, and some will return -1 until you reach the end of the result set. So it might work, but Perl can't tell you the actual number unless the database engine reports it accurately.

Comment: @Dave Sherohman, Re "While the fetchrow_array method does return an array", Nit: It's impossible for subs to return arrays. It returns a number of scalars ("list").

Comment: @ikegami - You got me. I know better than that. I blame my error on the author of DBI for naming the method `fetchrow_array` instead of `fetchrow_list`.